# Best way to set VNode attributes in Vue.js using TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

How does one set attributes on Vue.js tag nodes ([VNode](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/master/types/vnode.d.ts#L10)) programmatically without a need to define `vnode.data` and `vnode.data.attrs` each time?

The way I use is far from optimal:

```
const itemNode = h('div', item.title)
itemNode.data = {}
itemNode.data.attrs = {}
itemNode.data.attrs.class = 'some-class'
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured out with [The Data Object In-Depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#The-Data-Object-In-Depth)

```
const menuItemNode = h(
  'div',
  {
    class: {
      'some-good-class': true,
      'some-bad-class': false
    }
  },
  item.title
)
```